# Reading extra data in C++

Tags: c++

I have a file that consists of data points, and numbers associated with those data points. For example, the file looks something like:

```
(1,2) 45
(3,4) 12
(23,9) 6 90
(3,5) 4 8
```

For each data point, I want to set variables "int num1" and "int num2." As you can see, sometimes I have to read an extra number attached to my data point. When there is no extra number, I set num1 and num2 to the value given. I have no problem getting the x and y from the coordinate, but I'm not sure how to check to make sure I'm getting both numbers. I feel like I have to use getline(), but I'm not sure where to go from there. The file is saved as "ins."

```
char parentheses1, parentheses2, comma;
int x, y, num1, num2;
ins >> parentheses1 >> x >> comma >> y >> parentheses2;
ins >> num1 >> num2;
```

Comment: after you get what you want you can use `getline` to eat the rest of the line.

Comment: Kinda get the feeling you want us to write the code

Comment: Read each line into a std::string with getline and then parse the line.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take Option 2 from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301) as a basis for your code.

Read from the stringstream into x and y

```
iss >> parentheses1 >> x >> comma >> y >> parentheses2;
```

and then gather numbers until there are none left on the line

```
std::vector<int> numbers; // dynamic array of numbers
int temp; 
while (iss >> temp) // exits as soon as you can't read an int from the stream
{
    numbers.push_back(temp); // store in vector
}
```

You can simplify the above a bit if there are never more than, say, 2 numbers.